SmsBroadcastReceiver Intent Redirection Error
When I'm trying to publish my app on play store but im getting the intent redirection error in my broadcast receiver. Here is the related code.

class SmsBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    var smsBroadcastReceiverListener: SmsBroadcastReceiverListener? = null

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

        if (intent?.action == SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION) {

            val extras = intent.extras
            val smsRetrieverStatus = extras?.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS) as Status

            when (smsRetrieverStatus.statusCode) {
                CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS -> {

                    val messageIntent = extras.getParcelable<Intent>(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_CONSENT_INTENT)
                    smsBroadcastReceiverListener?.onSuccess(messageIntent)
                }
                CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT -> {
                    smsBroadcastReceiverListener?.onFailure()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sms Broadcast Receiver Listener
     */
    interface SmsBroadcastReceiverListener {
        /**
         * if common status success
         */
        fun onSuccess(intent: Intent?)
        /**
         * if common status timeout
         */
        fun onFailure()
    }
}

And here is my manifest file for my broadcast
        <receiver
            android:name=".broadcast.SmsBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

I couldn't find a solution can someone help ?
Tried to change my manifest file but it looks fine to me. Probably the problem is about my onReceive function but couldn't find a solution atm.

class SmsBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

var smsBroadcastReceiverListener: SmsBroadcastReceiverListener? = null

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    // Verify the intent action
    if (intent?.action == SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION) {
        val extras: Bundle? = intent.extras
        val smsRetrieverStatus = extras?.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS) as? Status

        // Validate the status is from the expected sender
        if (smsRetrieverStatus != null) {
            when (smsRetrieverStatus.statusCode) {
                CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS -> {
                    val messageIntent = extras.getParcelable<Intent>(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_CONSENT_INTENT)

                    // Validate the nested intent
                    if (validateIntent(context, messageIntent)) {
                        smsBroadcastReceiverListener?.onSuccess(messageIntent)
                    } else {
                        Log.w("SmsBroadcastReceiver", "Untrusted intent detected")
                    }
                }
                CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT -> {
                    smsBroadcastReceiverListener?.onFailure()
                }
                else -> {
                    Log.w("SmsBroadcastReceiver", "Unexpected status code: ${smsRetrieverStatus.statusCode}")
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.w("SmsBroadcastReceiver", "SmsRetriever status is null")
        }
    } else {
        Log.w("SmsBroadcastReceiver", "Unexpected intent action: ${intent?.action}")
    }
}

// Validate the nested intent
private fun validateIntent(context: Context?, intent: Intent?): Boolean {
    if (context == null || intent == null) return false

    // Check if the nested intent grants URI permissions
    val flags = intent.flags
    if ((flags and Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION != 0) ||
        (flags and Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION != 0)) {
        return false
    }

    // Ensure the nested intent is not harmful
    val componentName = intent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager)
    Log.d("SmsBroadcastReceiver", "Resolved ComponentName: $componentName")

    // Check if the intent comes from a trusted package
    val isValid = componentName?.packageName == "com.google.android.gms"
    Log.d("SmsBroadcastReceiver", "isValid: $isValid")

    return isValid
}

/**
 * Sms Broadcast Receiver Listener
 */
interface SmsBroadcastReceiverListener {
    /**
     * if common status success
     */
    fun onSuccess(intent: Intent?)

    /**
     * if common status timeout
     */
    fun onFailure()
} }


Have you tried this solution from Prasenjit?
im also facing the exact problem, and im about to try this solution. sorry i had to answer intead of just commenting. My reputation is below 50 i can't comment on your question directly.
To be more precise with my problem, it pointed me on my onSuccess. Your code is exactly the same with mine.
    private val smsBroadcastReceiver by lazy {
    SmsBroadcastReceiver().also {
        it.smsBroadcastReceiverListener =
            object : SmsBroadcastReceiver.SmsBroadcastReceiverListener {
                override fun onSuccess(intent: Intent?) {
                    intent?.let { context ->
                        smsBroadcastReceiverLauncher.launch(context)
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure() {}
            }
    }
}

right here when im about to launch the smsBroadCastRecieverLauncher. I asked if you already tried from Parsenjit since it makes sense it was said here
img at googleSupp.
If you already solved the problem may ask what are the things that you;ve done?

I already solved the issue and posted an answer for you.You can see it down below.
